# How to get the current path in a django view?

Tags: python, django, web-applications, django-views

So the question is really simple i need a method to get the current url in a class based view in django, requests.path doesnt work im not sure why - Do i need to import something? I tried : "from django.http import request" but that doesnt have an Attribute path.

Comment: In a CBV the request is available as an attribute on the view instance: e.g. `self.request.get_full_path()` should work.

Comment: hey thanks man you are my hero, this worked after i figured out that i had to use it in a function, in the view, which i pass self to.

Comment: Cheers! With more time, I might have added some more explanations ;-) but I guess you learned a bit figuring stuff out on your own.